# Two input field in line jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <input type="text" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month" data-native-menu="false">
    <input type="text" id="expiry_year" name="expiry_year" data-native-menu="false">
</fieldset>
```

I have this html. I'm using jquery mobile for building a form, but I can't make the two input fields on a single line. The second input field jumps to the next line. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4JcjW/)

You can modify the selector `.ui-input-text` changing the display property:

```
.ui-input-text {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Just to be sure of change the inputs inside this fieldset assign a classname:

```
<fieldset ... class="aside">
```

And then make more specific the CSS rule:

```
.aside .ui-input-text {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this one is working.But When the tried onmobile,the second fieldiscoming down?Any help?

Comment: Try adding `width:50%` too or in `.aside` add `white-space:nowrap` @user3244208

Comment: can you make some demo ? @user3244208

Comment: No it didnt..I have used the same code you have used in the fiddle.You can even check the filled,by resizing the output window

Comment: great! it did the job!